# Django - iterating the elements of a dictionary and saving them generates problems at the level of connections to the database?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm working with a survey app, so I need to save all the answers a user gives in the database. The way I'm doing it is this:

```
for key, value in request.POST.items(): 
       if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': # I don't want to save the token info
          item = Item.objects.get(pk=key) # I get the question(item) I want to save
          if item == None:
            return render(request, "survey/error.html")
          Answer.objects.create(item= item, answer=value, user = request.user)
```

Taking into account that django by default closes connections to the database (i.e. does not use persistent connections). My question is:

1. In case the dictionary has for example the answer to 60 questions (so it will iterate 60 times), would it open and close the connections 60 times, or does it only do it once?
2. Is there a better way to save POST information manually? (without using django forms, since for various reasons I currently need to do it manually)

Comment: It will make **120** queries, furthermore if the `Item` does not exist, it will not render the `error.html` page, but raise an error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your comment. Two questions: 1.why 120 and not 60, if I'm iterating 60 times?
2. why it will raise an error, if : if item == None:
            return render(request, "survey/error.html") ?

Comment: because `.get(..)` already raises an error if it can not find the given row. It does *not* return `None` in that case.

Comment: I'd like to ask you two questions. **1.** Why do you say it would be 120 querysets and not 60? **2.** Does each queryset open and close the connection to the database? Or does the connection open at the beginning of the **for** and close at the end of iteration?

Comment: usually connections are managed in a connection pool, so no typically the connection is not closed. The reason why there are 120, is because for every question, we make a query with the `Item.objects.get(..)`, and one for the `Answer.objects.create(..)`, so for 60 items, we get 60*2 is 120 queries.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your answer. Regarding the connection pool, does django by default manage the connections using a connection pool? or is it something that should be configured with external libraries?

Comment: see here about settings about pooling: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/databases/#transacation-pooling-and-server-side-cursors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely is *not* a good way to store `Answer`s in bulk, since:

1. you each time fetch the `Item` object for every single question;
2. your code does *not* handle the case correctly where an item is missing: in that case it will raise an exception, and the Django middleware will (likely) render a 500 page; and
3. it will make several calls to create all these objects.

We can create objects in bulk to reduce the number of queries. Typically we will create all elements with a single query, although depending on the database and the amount of data, it might take a limited number of queries.

We furtermore do *not* need to fetch the related `Item` objects, *at all*, we can just set the `item_id` field instead, the "twin" of the `item` `ForeignKey` field, like:

from django.db import IntegrityError

```
try:
    answers = [
        Answer(item_id=key, answer=value, user=request.user)
        for key, value in request.POST.items()
        if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
    ]

    Answer.objects.bulk_create(answers)
except IntegrityError:
    return render(request, 'survey/error.html')
```

The [**`bulk_create`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) will thus insert all the objects in a small number of queries and thus significantly reduce the time of the request.

Note however that `bulk_create` has some *limitations* (listed on the documentation page). It might be useful to read those carefully and take them into account. Although I think in the given case, these are not relevant, it is always better to know the limitations of the tools you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When using django forms and saving data through them, internally uses this method (bulk_create)?

Comment: @Ale: no, since a `ModelForm` is typically used to construct a *single* object. There are however `FormSet`s. I'm not completely familiar with how the formsets implementation however.